# Cypress for multiple windows

Tags: cypress

have a scenario where on launching the application, redirects to a new window for authentication and on entering the creds, the user is allowed to access the application. As multiple window handling is a trade off for cypress, is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Cypress can't work with multiple windows.

Follow: [Multiple browsers open at the same time](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/trade-offs#Multiple-browsers-open-at-the-same-time)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).